# Understanding folder "image" as a controller

Tags: zend-framework, controller

When I try to access the url http://localhost/mysite/public/images/grey-arrow.gif in a controller in my application I get the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (images)' in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:242 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 D:\Users\rnem\www\mysite\application\Bootstrap_Aplicativo.php(64): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2 D:\Users\rnem\www\regnet3.0\home\index.php(3): include_once('D:\Users\rnem\w...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php  on line 242

Why is it thinking images is a controller instead of a folder as it is?!

Answer (score 2):

What do you have in your .htaccess file in /public?

Comment: Indeed, this happens when your RewriteRules either match all requests, or match requests that don't correspond to a file on disk

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have

```
# Rewrite rules for Zend Framework
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

# Security: Don't allow browsing of directories
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to access your site via a virtual host configuration, instead of just path-ing out via `localhost`. I suspect the URL re-writer can't find your image file because it doesn't know that `public` is the root directory files are served from, so it falls back on trying to interpret the URL as a controller action.

Creating a virtual host is covered in the [Zend Framework Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html)

Answer (score 0):

The default htaccess for zend is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Give that a go. If that doesn't work the vhosts mentioned above should be:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot D:/Users/rnem/www/mysite/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Put that into your vhosts conf file, remember to uncomment the vhosts line in your httpd.conf. This might help, http://www.tildemark.com/software/servers/setting-up-virtual-hosts-with-xampp-running-on-windows-xp.html, otherwise there's plenty of giudes on google